# After I send text to a text box using selenium how do i save that text as a variable(string) and then print that to console

Tags: c#, selenium

After I send text to a text box using selenium how do i save that text as a variable(string) and then print that to console.

```
ie. field.sendkeys("name")
    IWebElement name = driver.FindElement(By.field("firstname"));
    Console.Writline("Name: "+name);
```

something like that?

When i run it I get Name:

Comment: was this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dylan - Take a look at Faker.net as a nuget package if you are looking for Random Data.

```
        ex.
        string rndFirstName = Faker.Name.First();
        string rndMiddleName = Faker.Name.First();
        string rndLastName = Faker.Name.Last();
```

then you can find the input box

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname").sendKeys(rndFirstName);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("middlename").sendKeys(rndMiddleName);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("lastname").sendKeys(rndLastName);
```

Then to see what the field value now has:

```
var newFirst = driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname").GetAttribute("value");
Console.WriteLine("Name: "+ newFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name variable is IWebElement object type, if you want to print text then you should put that text in some string variable.

Something like:

```
string name = "some name";
field.sendKeys(name);
Console.WriteLine("Name: "+ name);
```

Comment: What I am wanting is to sendkeys.(randomText). Then I want to console write what the text in the textbox has been changed to.